# Los cors no me dejan hacer una petición con JQUERY

Tags: jquery, cors

tal y como dice el título, resulta que al hacer un load() de un objeto en concreto no me deja hacerlo por culpa de los cors.¿Hay alguna manera de solucionar esto? Os adjunto el código y el error. El código de abajo no es necesario que lo leáis todo(creo), es sólo una petición a la api. Muchas gracias de antemano!

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'Aqui va mi url' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

```
function modificar(){
    const row = document.getElementsByClassName("modificacion");
    let cambia = 0;
    let idnodo = [];
    let i = 0;
    for(item of info){
        let x = row[i].selectedIndex
        if(row[i].options[x].value != item.state){
            idnodo.push(item.id);
            cambia = 1;
            let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.open("PUT", "http://localhost:3000/api/nodes", true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({
                id : item.id,
                state: row[i].options[x].value
            }));
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    console.log(this.response);
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    if(cambia){
        let mensaje
        if(idnodo.lenght != 1){
            mensaje = confirm("¿Estás seguro de que quieres modificar el estado de estos coches?\n"+ idnodo.join("\n"));
        }
        else{
            mensaje = confirm("¿Estás seguro de que quieres modificar el estado de este coche?\n"+ idnodo.join("\n"));
        }
        if(mensaje){
           $("#tablacoches").load("../indexAdministrador.html");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Los problemas de CORS se solucionan desde el backend. ¿Qué lenguaje usas para crear tus endpoints?

Comment: Uso nodejs. Aunque al final lo solucioné. Para que me haga bien el load tuve que poner dentro la ruta de la petición que hago a la API. De esta forma me ha funcionado. Gracias igualmente!